# Return the ids of failed logins

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I have a query to return the ids of failed logins that are newer than a supplied date, and also newer than the last successful login.

Table:

```
#######################################################
#                   user_attributes                   #
#######################################################
# id # u_id #        label      #  attribute_datetime #
#######################################################
# 1  #  33  #    failed_login   # 2012-05-21 09:03:00 #
# 2  #  33  # succcessful_login # 2012-05-21 09:04:00 #
#######################################################
```

Query:

```
SELECT  count(id)
FROM    `user_attributes` as ua
WHERE   u_id = 33
AND label = 'failed_login'
AND ua.attribute_datetime > '2012-05-21 03:04:00'
AND ua.attribute_datetime > (
    SELECT  attribute_datetime
    FROM    `user_attributes`
    WHERE   u_id = 33
    AND label = 'successful_login'
);
```

Returns:

```
##############
# result_set #
##############
#     id     #
##############
#            #
##############
```

Now if we add another failed login:

```
#######################################################
#                   user_attributes                   #
#######################################################
# id # u_id #        label      #  attribute_datetime #
#######################################################
# 3  #  33  #    failed_login   # 2012-05-21 09:10:00 #
#######################################################
```

And run the query again it should return this:

```
##############
# result_set #
##############
#     id     #
##############
#     3      #
##############
```

Is there a better way to write this query? I am looking to improve the speed of the query as this is going to run every time a user logs in, and the table is going to be large if not huge.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.  Have you run Explain against it to ensure you are using indexes?

Comment: Where do you get the *supplied date* from?

Comment: @dreza - I have never used explain I will have to look into it.

Comment: @palacsint - The supplied date is given via PHP when the query is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good to me as well except if you are looking for the ids of the failed logins you would not want to count the ids (SELECT count(id)) but instead just select the id (SELECT id).

Comment: I am not concerned with returning the ids but the number of ids